# How can I get my switch case to act on JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, compiler-errors, jframe, switch-statement

I have managed to build the initial start screen (`JFrame`) for my program but I can't seem to get the buttons to go the the screen I want. The error I get when I try to build it is:

```
error: incompatible types: JFrame cannot be converted to int
```

Here is my code:

```
    import javax.swing.*;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    public class MovieGenerator extends JFrame
    {//Buttons
    JButton titleButton;
    JButton actorButton;
    JButton genreButton;
    JButton runtimeButton;
    JButton ratingButton;
    JButton addButton;
    JButton randomButton;
    //Main GUI
    public MovieGenerator() 
    {
        super("Main Menu");
        JFrame main = new JFrame();
        setLookAndFeel();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(1000,200);
        GridLayout grid = new GridLayout(2,4);
        setLayout(grid);
        titleButton = new JButton("Sort by Title");
        actorButton = new JButton("Find by Actor");
        genreButton = new JButton("Sort by Genre");
        runtimeButton = new JButton("Sort by Runtime");
        ratingButton = new JButton("Sort by Rating");
        addButton = new JButton("Add a new movie to collection");
        randomButton = new JButton("Random movie");
        //Containers
        add(titleButton);
        add(actorButton);
        add(genreButton);
        add(runtimeButton);
        add(ratingButton);
        add(addButton);
        add(randomButton);
        setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        MovieGenerator mov = new MovieGenerator();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        JFrame main = new JFrame();
        switch (main)
        {
            case 0:
            {
                int titleButton = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "How do you want to sort?", "Main Menu",JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, 
            new Object[] {"Alphabetically Descending", "Alphabetically Ascending",}, " ");
            }
            //  break;

            case 1:
            {
                int genreButton = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Set genre", "Sort by Genre",JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, 
            new Object[] {"Drama", "Comedy","Action/Adventure","Horror","Romance","SciFi/Fantasy","Western","Foreign","Animation"}, " ");
            }

            //  break;
            case 2:
            {       
                int runtimeButton = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Set runtime range", "Sort by Runtime",JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, 
            new Object[] {"90-110 minutes", "111-130 minutes","131-150 minutes","151-170 minutes","171+ minutes"}, " ");
            }
            //  break;
            case 3:
            {
                int ratingButton = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Set ratings range", "Sort by Ratings",JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, 
            new Object[] {"Search 0-10%", "Search 11-20%","Search 21-30%", "Search 31-40%","Search 41-50%", 
                          "Search 51-60%", "Search 61-70%","Search 71-80%", "Search 81-90%","Search 91-100%"}, " ");
            }
            //  break;
            case 4:
            {
                int randomButton = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Randomize your selection", "Random!",JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, 
            new Object[] {"Randomize!"}, " ");
            //break;
            }           

        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Can  you explain  your purpose at this line `int n = (int) main;` ?

Comment: I think you have a misunderstanding with how GUI's work.  GUI's are event driven environments, that is, you have to wait till something happens and then respond to it.  See [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/), [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html)
 and [How to Write an Action Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) for some more details...

Answer (score 0):

> "error: incompatible types: JFrame cannot be converted to int"

The Error is self explanatory JFrame Object cannot be converted to int

```
int n = (int) main;//This line is the root cause
```

and As [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) Says

> A switch works with the byte, short, char, and int primitive data
>   types. It also works with enumerated types (discussed in Enum Types),
>   the String class, and a few special classes that wrap certain
>   primitive types: Character, Byte, Short, and Integer (discussed in
>   Numbers and Strings).

So Switch will not work with `JFrame`

Comment: Yes you will get because Switch case does not support JFrame Object , Read my updated Answer

Comment: I strongly suggest you to read [Event Handling](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/swing/swing_event_handling.htm)

Answer (score 0):

As other answers and comments state, you cannot get a integer from a frame. Swing simply doesn't work like that.

Instead you can add "action listeners" to the buttons. These are simple "callbacks" that are invoked when the button is pressed.

This can be done inside the MovieGenerator constructor like this

```
titleButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int titleButton = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "How do you want to sort?", "Main Menu", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null,
                new Object[] { "Alphabetically Descending", "Alphabetically Ascending", }, " ");

    }
});
```

or outside in the main method with an appropriate getter, or shudder, field access.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    MovieGenerator mov = new MovieGenerator();
    mov.getTitleButton().addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            int titleButton = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "How do you want to sort?", "Main Menu", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null,
                    new Object[] { "Alphabetically Descending", "Alphabetically Ascending", }, " ");

        }
    });
    // etc
}
```